# Hi, Can someone help me understand the javascript syntax, especially in data: parts

Tags: javascript, php, syntax

I'm downloading a calendar html/php document from internet and want to understand how it works. Can some help me understand what this java script does?
there are getCalender function already in the same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCalendar(target_div,year,month){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'functions.php',
            data:'func=getCalender&year='+year+'&month='+month,
            success:function(html){
                $('#'+target_div).html(html);
            }
        });
    }
```

thank you

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ read the docs, it's all explained there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript in your post is using jquerys ajax function to make a request to a backend `function.php` file. the parmeters passed are year and month. And looking at the `success` callback it would appear the `function.php` file is building and returning the Html to display the calender.

Ajax is used to asynchronously load content so you dont need to refresh the page.

Here is more information about jquerys ajax functionality

> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

**Data being sent**

So looking at the key value fields being sent to the `function.php` file these are the `POST`ed data. so you would use `PHP` super global variable `$_POST` to access these.

eg :

```
<?php
$_POST['func'] = 'getCalender';
$_POST['year'] = 2017 //assuming the value stored in the year variable
$_POST['month'] = 'May //assuming the value stored in the month variable
```

In the example above it looks as though i'm assigning values to the super-variable, which Iam, But what i'm trying to do is show you an example of what they might equal and how you can access the data

Comment: thank you for the links. can you get more in depth in "data:'func=getCalender&year='+year+'&month='+month," part? (can't this info in the link) what is the syntax to pass the parameter? is it the "+" sign or "&" sign. thank you

Comment: @Jo ha the `+` is just concatenating the strings to the variables.  the `&` is the delimiter to say when one key value pair ends and the next one begins.